# How to assign fields of a struct from scanning stdin?

Tags: c

I want the program to extract data from the user through the console, by scanning `stdin` with the `scanf()` and `fgets()` and assign the values to named structs, to eventually print them out.

Right the following code is not working. The problem is the code does not recognize the scanned input and the array `corona` and fails to assign it into that array at index "0".

Here's the code.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct {
    char name[100];
    char phone[100];
} Person;

typedef struct {
    char location[100];
    char time[100];
} Event;

typedef struct {
    Person person;
    Event event;
} Corona;

int main() {

/*help variables*/
    char* name2;
    char* number2;
    char* location2;
    char* date2;

    Corona corona[28]; //creating list with 28 objects just because. it could be 5 or x too.
    printf("Name");
    fgets(name2, 50, stdin); //user input for name
    printf("Nummer/location/date");
    scanf("%s %s %s", number2, location2, date2); //user input for phone number, location and date

    corona[0]= *(Corona*)malloc(sizeof (Corona)); //allocating memory for array
    corona[0]={{("%s",name2),("%s", number2)}, {("%s", location2),("%s", date2)}};

/*printing out the information of array "corona" with index 0"*/
    printf("Name: %s\n", corona[0].person.name);
    printf("Phone: %s\n", corona[0].person.phone);
    printf("Location: %s\n", corona[0].event.location);
    printf("Time: %s\n", corona[0].event.time);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: you do not need to allocate memory for corona array, you already allocated the array on the stack

Comment: You cannot use `fgets` with a `char *` that points to nothing. You need to pass a buffer, either in the form of a `char buf[100]` and then use `sizeof but` as the second argument to `fgets`, or allocate a dynamic bit of memory using `malloc` and pass the size you pass to `malloc` also to `fgets`.

Comment: You are assigning dynamic memory to `corona[0]` which is already allocated on the stack. Don't just do stuff, you need to understand when you need to allocate memory and when not. It seems like you have skipped a few lessons.

Comment: You will have trouble mixing `fgets` and `scanf` in the same program.  They don't always play well together.

Answer (score 0):

lets fix one part of this and see if you can fix the rest

```
printf("Nummer/location/date");
scanf("%s %s %s", corona[0].person.phone,
       corona[0].event.location,
       corona[0].event.time);
```

no need for any mallocs, fancy casts or whatever that assignment line is tryong to do

ie these lines

```
corona[0]= *(Corona*)malloc(sizeof (Corona)); //allocating memory for array
corona[0]={{("%s",name2),("%s", number2)}, {("%s", location2),("%s", date2)}};
```